# Javascript History Back Clear Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have two forms (A and B) which is called through CI controller. It has warning alert in each function in controller to alert when user input is invalid. On both alert there is a javascript which redirect the page to the form page (history -1) after alert clicked. My alert code is:

```
echo "<script>alert('Invalid Input!'); location.href='javascript:window.history.go(-1);'</script>";
```

I found something strange between the two forms. In form A, after the alert clicked every input that user has typed still remains (this is what I want), but in form B it is cleared. I want to keep what user has typed in the form B as it has so many forms.

Please if you have any solution for it

Here is snippet of my form A code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/register/addmember" name="formregister" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center>
        <table id="form_register">              
            <tr>
                <td>Email* </td>
                <td id="txtemail"><input placeholder="your email" maxlength="255" type="email" name="email" size="50"/> <br/></td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                <td>Username*</td>
                <td id="txtusername"><input placeholder="your username" maxlength="255" type="text" name="username" size="50"/> <br/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password*  </td>
                <td id="txtpassword"><input placeholder="your password"  maxlength="255"type="password" name="password" size="50"/><br/></td>
            </tr>                       

            <tr>
                <td>Photo*</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="photo"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>                   
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="agreement" name="agreement"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i>I accept the terms and conditions</i></a></input></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>                
                <td align="right" style="padding-right:15px;"><input type="submit" disabled value="Register" name="submit" id="btnRegister"/></td>
                <td align="left" style="padding-left:15px;"><input type="reset" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel"/></td>                                        
            </tr>           
        </table>
    </center>       
</form>
```

And here is snippet of form B:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/festival/adddata/" name="newdata" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div id="edit-area-left">
                    <center>        
                    <table>
                    <tr><td></td>
                        <td><u><b>Main information</b></u></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Event Name*</td> 
                        <td><input type="text" maxlength="255" name="eventname" size="50" placeholder="Event Name"/></td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time of Event</td>                          
                        <td><input type="text" maxlength="255" name="time" size="50" placeholder="Time of event"></td>
                    </tr>                                           
                </table>
            </center>
                </div>
                <div id="edit-area-right">
                <center>
                <table> 
                    <tr><td></td>
                        <td><u><b>Event Description</b></u></td></tr>
                    <tr>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td>Event Desctiprion*</td>
                        <td><textarea cols="37" rows="5" name="detailevent" id="detailevent" style="resize:none;" maxlength="2000" placeholder="event Detail"></textarea><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td></td>
                        <td><u><b>Image*</b></u></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>                            
                        <td><input type="file" name="image"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:15px;"><input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" id="profile-edit-button"/></td>                     
                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:15px;"><input type="reset" value="Cancel" id="profile-edit-button"/></td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table>
                </center>
                </div>
            </form>
```

PS: I'm using Codeigniter.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it better if we can your form html

Comment: Question updated @sri

Comment: You should probably use a proper redirect rather than JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions here. First of all just to confirm you will not be able to clear history if you just use `window.history.go(-1)`, so that:

**Solution 1 (Recommended)**

I would suggest you to handle form validation via AJAX and then you can control which fields you may clear and which you want to remain with filled data.

**Solution 2**

You can redirect user back and pass a random parameter which will clear (all) fields, like this (the a.html is just for sample, you should replace it with URL of the page where you have forms):

```
echo "<script>alert('Invalid Input!'); location.href='a.html?' + Math.random();</script>";
```

Comment: History, do you mean what user typed? Yes, I don't want to clear it. I can't use the second solution as it will against the session of the page. And for the first solution, I'm going to explore it more but still want to validate it in server. Thanks. Or have you tried using:  <?php session_cache_limiter('private-no-expire'); ?> to prevent it?